# How to check real-time change in database with php websocket?

Tags: php, jquery, sockets, websocket

I want to update a `div` only when there is a change in a certain field in the database, I am currently using `setTimeout (listComment, 3000);`, but I want to switch to websocket because of performance issues and the impact it causes on traffic. I looked for some examples on the internet, but I only found examples of chats, and it's not what I need.

Does anyone have a hint of how to check changes in database with websocket only on a `div`?

Answer (score 0):

Websocket is effective when you send data between client and server, but how are you gonna get that data? You should probably setTimeout and get data from the database (e.g) every 3 seconds. exactly as you did. 
And if you gonna use NodeJs WebSocket you should make curl request to your PHP server.

I guess moving to WebSocket will increase the effort on your servers instead of your client.

Anyway if you would use WebSocket on PHP I would suggest Ratchet and if you have a little bit experience with nodeJs I suggest socket.io

Comment: Hi, Adam.

The data will come from a Mysql table using PHP and this is ready, but I have never worked with websockets. The system is for comments, as it happens here and will have many users. How could I do this dynamically using websockets?

Comment: I can't type your whole code. you have to try with ratchet, you may require PHP 7 and composer.